# Block truncate and log attempt to another table

Tags: mysql

How can we block someone from truncating table and if some one attempts to truncate then that incident should be recorded. Something like a trigger but unfortunately truncate does not work with triggers.

Does any one know any solution similar to trigger?

Comment: As per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) the user shouldn't get the DROP-Privilege. Apart from that there is no trigger like mechanism in 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this method helps. Create a stored procedure to truncate the table and the table name can be a input to the same.

For all the DB users, restrict the drop access and educate them to use only this procedure to truncate the table. In that procedure, track the needed details in a audit table.